# incorrect Baudrate of Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

i build a small c program to working on Serial port in raspberry pi.
as follow :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "serialport_layer.h"
int main()
{
    int ret = openSerialPort("/dev/ttyS0", 115200);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("can't open serial port\n");
        return -1; // unable to open serial port
    }
    const char *msg = " Hello from Raspberry pi )\n";
    while (1)
    {
        write(ret,msg,strlen(msg));
        usleep(100 * 1000 * 10);
    }
}
```

the function openSerialPort is from WiringPi library.
however i am getting unstable baud-rate and undetectable !!
this is the terminal output:
[Unstable BaudRate output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEGfw.png).

i am using power supply with 5.8 v output!!!

i am using :

1. cross-compiling using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
2. 2023-10-10-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite Distribution.
3. raspberry pi 3 model B

any suggestions please !!

when i powered it with 5.0v, all the output is wrong, i get some correct output just when using power it with 5.8v. !!!

Comment: Your title does not make sense. A mismatch in baudrate will result in reading garbled data. But reading garbled data does not necessarily mean that there is "*incorrect baudrate*"; i.e. there are other possible causes. What evidence do you have? Did you measure anything with an oscilloscope? What is the actual hardware involved? Is this RS-232 or TTL serial connection? **Why did you even consider increasing the supply voltage by 16%???** Is this really a programming problem?